# Выбрать из массива через три элемента

Tags: javascript

Такой вопрос, приходит массив строк, надо изменить свойство у каждой 1,2,3...7,8,9...13,14,15 - то есть через три строки. Как их вычислить? Через одну все просто, а вот как через три сделать не пойму(

Comment: Из общечеловеческих методов - двойной цикл, или обход всех в одинарном цикле, но применение только к тем, чей индекс по модулю 6 будет в нужном диапазоне.

Answer (score 3):

В каждой итерации цикла проверяете, не делится ли инкремент без остатка на 3. Если делится, увеличиваете его сразу на 3:

```js
const arr = [
  'строка 1',
  'строка 2',
  'строка 3',
  'строка 4',
  'строка 5',
  'строка 6',
  'строка 7',
  'строка 8',
  'строка 9',
  'строка 10',
  'строка 11',
  'строка 12',
  'строка 13',
  'строка 14',
  'строка 15',
  'строка 16',
  'строка 17',
  'строка 18',
  'строка 19',
  'строка 20',
];

for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = 'изменено';
  if((i+1)%3 == 0) {
     i+=3;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: В том то и дело, что не могу увеличивать на три.  В функцию приходят последоватьно 1,2,3,4...И надо понять, что для 1,2,3 возвращатьtrue, а для 4,5,6 false

Comment: @JavDev, тогда покажите код Ваш целиком - как он работает и как надо, чтобы работал

Answer (score 2):

Может `parseInt(i/3)%2` ?

```js
const arr = Array(15).fill(0).map((_, i) => `строка ` + (i+1));

console.log(arr.filter((_, i) => ~parseInt(i/3)%2));
```